# What steps, as a community, should we take to correct the flow of questions between StackOverflow and DSSE?

Tags: discussion

For the first time in a while I went to StackOverflow, looking for question to answer under the `python` tag.

I found many questions, including some with high bounties, related to Data Science and not code. Meanwhile in DSSE I find dozens of questions been closed because they are code related.

I mean, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421475/dcgan-debugging-getting-just-garbage) question, it's entirely about why some pre-processing steps don't work on his DCGAN. There were others, I just not finding them on the browser history.

I feel that there is a strong effort from DSSE Moderators and high reputation members to migratted questions asked on DSSE to SO when they should. But I fail to see a flow from SO to DSSE when questions should be asked here.

Comment: The most obvious thing is to follow SO and flag questions for migration.  Using the tags `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, and any tags for packages you're familiar with can help.

Comment: On our site I have seen questions where instead of flagging or voting on migration, a comment was left saying something like "it might be better to ask this question on XXX". Is that an accepted way of handling it across SX or considered offensive?

Comment: I think that's needed, after all flagging or voting to close a question doesn't say where it is supposed to go, and waiting until moderation migrates it might take a while and let them overwhelmed. A person can delete their question and place it elsewhere

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte For migration, you should flag "in need of moderator intervention," in which case you _can_ say where it is supposed to go.

Comment: I do, either case I could point to the OP that he could do it himself and save him time. Since he won't have to wait. Also, there is a closing vote for that and it doesn't allow us to point where to, so adding a comment is the polite thing to do, the same applies to questions that need clarity, if possible post what is needed from it.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte According to [this post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/stepping-down-as-a-moderator) a user from SE AI has been temp banned for this on SE Stats. That is why it would be helpful if moderators could provide guidance what the right approach is.

Comment: The behavior of Stats SE moderators was abusive, so was the behavior of the AI SE moderator which spammed another SE site. There is no indication what so ever that suggesting the redirection of a question is discouraged or that comments aren't the right place for it.